# connectivity_service in android 4.03 causing NPE?

Tags: android, libgdx

I released a game on the android market recently and got my first error report through ACRA today. The exception is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sweee.db.AndroidDBHelper.java.util.ArrayList getScores()(SourceFile:65)
at sweee.com.screens.HighScoreScreen.void show()(SourceFile:180)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.void setScreen(com.badlogic.gdx.Screen)(SourceFile:59)
at sweee.com.screens.LevelDoneScreen.void render$133aeb()(SourceFile:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.void render()(SourceFile:46)
at com.sweee.main.SweeeMain.void render()(SourceFile:125)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.void
onDrawFrame(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10)(SourceFile:452)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1462)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1216)
```

Through ACRA I know the device was an Acer Iconia A100 with ICS 4.03 running. I unfortuntly cannot reproduce the error on the emulator (tried connected to the internet and airplane mode). The line on which it claims to throw the NPE, is a call to my Function "isConnected()" which does this:

```
public boolean isConnected() {
        final ConnectivityManager connectManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // Return true if connected, either in 3G or wi-fi
        final boolean connected = (connectManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || connectManager.getNetworkInfo(
            ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED);
        return connected;
}
```

I am pretty much clueless and would like to fix this bug. Is there any general problem with this method to check for an existing internet connection that is specific to ICS 4.03 or the Iconia A100?

Maybe someone who owns an Iconia A100 could do me a favor and try to reproduce the failure? The game is free on android market [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sweee.main). Thank you very much for your time and any possible answer or hint.

edit:

```
@Override
    public ArrayList<Score> getScores() {

    Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().query("scores", null, null, null, null, null, "points DESC");
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Score s = new Score(c.getString(1), c.getInt(2), getBoolFromInt(c.getInt(3)), getBoolFromInt(c.getInt(4)));
            if (!scores.contains(s)) {
                scores.add(s);
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    if (isConnected()) {

        syncDB();
    }

    return scores;
}
```

this is the function that causes the NPE. Line 65 would be

```
if(isConnected()) {
```

the ArrayList scores is instantiated when the class gets (one of the first calls of the app, this does not get called before, should therefore not be null). 
neither a call to scores.contains(s) nor add should cause a NPE, right?
I just don't get it. Especially as this code is running fine on meanwhile 9 other devices...

I really appreciate any more help. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this: `at com.sweee.db.AndroidDBHelper.java.util.ArrayList getScores()(SourceFile:65)`. Which is line SourceFile:65? There is something wrong with an arraylist here...

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I edited my initial question to give more information. I just can't find the situation in which something in this function could be null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is on this line

```
final boolean connected =
        (connectManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED 
        || connectManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED);
```

That happens because `(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);` returns null.

Look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29). It says 
`Returns: The service or null if the name does not exist.` According to this, the name `Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE` does not exist. Could it be an OS implementation issue? Probably.

I had a somewhat "similar" situation: I wanted to start an activity to handle the `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS`, and on my device it worked (OS 2.3.7), but on some other devices (OS version above and below 2.3.7) it didn't work. Could it be an OS implementation issue? Most likely.

Since you can not reproduce the crash,

1. buy an `Acer Iconia A100 with ICS 4.03` and test on it
2. use some trickery. By this I mean the following:

Release an update with the following code and hope that your user with the Acer Iconia updates the app:

```
public boolean isConnected() {
    final ConnectivityManager connectManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // trickery
    if (connectManager == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("connectManager is null!");
    }
    // end trickery

    // Return true if connected, either in 3G or wi-fi
    final boolean connected =
        (connectManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED 
        || connectManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED);
    return connected;
}
```

This way you could get a crash report with this specific message. This way you could deduce some conclusions.

Anyway, if you just want to make your app work, check `connectManager` against `null`.

Hope this helps.

### EDIT:

Or, just do the following:

```
public boolean isConnected() {
    // final ConnectivityManager connectManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final ConnectivityManager connectManager = null;

    // Return true if connected, either in 3G or wi-fi
    final boolean connected =
        (connectManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED 
        || connectManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED);
    return connected;
}
```

and see if the stacktrace is the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am currently at work, so I will test the method you suggested in the EDIT part and see if the stack trace is the same. It sounds somewhat reasonable that this could be a reason for a NPE, but the Connectivity_Service is supported on api level 1 and this is also not failing on the emulator. I hope that this is the reason for the error, and I will of course supply an update which will notify me. I will mark this as the answer once i checked if the stacktrace is the same.

Comment: Even though `CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE` is supported since API level 1, it still could be an OS implementation issue. The Android platform is pretty fragmented, each company has it's own custom version of OS.

Comment: Keep me up to date please, even if this method does not solve your problem. Thanks

Comment: Hey bicska88, the resulting stacktrace when setting connectMannager to null is the same that I got through ACRA. I am currently adding a fix to my game and will release the update soon. Thank you very much for your investigation! Best, Tim

Answer (score 3):

I recently had this problem with `isConnect()` method in Acer Iconia A100

the solution that I found was changing `isConnect()` method like below and it worked very well!

I just put hole code in a try catch and when it throw a `nullPointerException` I return true

you can see code  here:

```
    public Boolean isConnect() {

    try{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


    if (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == etworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
            || cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() ==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        return true;
    }


}
```